# Backround Image Not Appearing in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

So this is my code for a school project meant to make an app to order pizza. I can't seem to get the backround image to appear after running the code, and I've tried switching the "root" to "frame" but it responds with "name 'frame' is not defined".

```
import tkinter as tk

# Window
root=tk.Tk()
root.title(" Mastrella's Mozzarella Pizza's ")

# Canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,height = 600 , width = 1000)
canvas.pack()

backround_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='wallpaper.png')
backround_label = tk.Label(root, image=backround_image)
backround_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# Frame
frame = tk.Frame(root)
#frame.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
frame.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

# Label
label = tk.Label(frame, text = "Mastrella's Mozzarella Pizza's", bg = 'black', fg = 'white',  width=200, height=2)
label.config(font=("Courier", 35))
label.pack()

# Button
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Order Pizza", bg = 'red',fg = 'white')
button.config(font=("Courier", 20))
button.pack(side = 'bottom')

# pizza size backround label
label = tk.Label(frame, bg = 'red', height=10, width=16)
label.place(x = 10, y = 145)

# toppings backround label
label = tk.Label(frame, bg = 'red', height=20, width=15)
label.place(x = 190, y = 150)

# pizza size
label = tk.Label(frame, text = "Pizza Size", bg = 'black', fg = 'white', height=1, width=10)
label.config(font=("Courier", 15))
label.place(x = 20, y = 160)

# pizza sizes
checkButtonMushroom = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Large", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonMushroom.place(x = 20, y = 200)

checkButtonMushroom = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Medium", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonMushroom.place(x = 20, y = 230)

checkButtonMushroom = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Small", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonMushroom.place(x = 20, y = 260)

# Label
label = tk.Label(frame, text = "Toppings", bg = 'black',fg = 'white', height=1, width=10)
label.config(font=("Courier", 15))
label.place(x = 200, y = 160)

# toppings
checkButtonMushroom = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Mushrooms", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonMushroom.place(x = 200, y = 200)

checkButtonOlives = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Olives", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonOlives.place(x = 200, y = 230)

checkButtonPepperoni = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Pepperoni", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonPepperoni.place(x = 200, y = 260)

checkButtonHotPeppers = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Hot Peppers", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonHotPeppers.place(x = 200, y = 290)

checkButtonExtraCheese = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Extra Cheese", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonExtraCheese.place(x = 200, y = 320)

checkButtonBacon = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Bacon", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonBacon.place(x = 200, y = 350)

checkButtonHam = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Ham", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonHam.place(x = 200, y = 380)

checkButtonOnion = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Onion", bg = 'black', fg = 'grey')
checkButtonOnion.place(x = 200, y = 410)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this program the backround image does not show up and I have no idea how to solve this problem. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: The frame sits on top of the background image and is the same size.  Unless the frame is transparent, the background is not going to show through.  I don't know if Tk even offers transparent windows.

Comment: I found out the issue was that my frame was after the backround, switching them around fixed the issue

Comment: Jordan: If you do that, can you still see the other stuff, too?

Answer (score 1):

Just re-arrange your code so the `frame` is defined, then replace `root` with `frame`:

```py
# Rest of your code above

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

backround_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='wallpaper.png')
backround_label = tk.Label(frame, image=backround_image) # Use frame instead of root
backround_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# Rest of your code below
```

Answer (score -1):

> I can't seem to get the backround image to appear after running the
> code, and I've tried switching the "root" to "frame" but it responds
> with "name 'frame' is not defined"

The problem can be fixed.

- On line 16 change `root` to `canvas`. `tk.Frame(canvas)`
- On line 21, 31, 35, 37 and 54, frame to root. tk.Label(root,..)
- Online 31 and 36 set `width` to 20.
- For every `Checkbutton` widgets. change `frame` to `root`.
  `tk.Checkbutton(root,...)`

That all!.

Screenshot:

[image]